# Rx sequential groupBy (partition stream)

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a stream of events:

```
event.EventTime: 1s-----2s----3s----4s----5s----6s---
stream:          A-B-C--D-----------------E-F---G-H--
```

An event looks like this:

```
public class Event
{
  public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

`EventTime` should correspond to a time at which the event arrives, but there can be a small delay. The events are not supposed to arrive out-of-order, though.

Now, when I specify an grouping interval, say 1 second, I expect the stream to be grouped like this

```
1s-------2s----3s----4s----5s-----6s---
[A-B-C]--[D]---[ ]---[ ]---[E-F]--[G-H]
```

(notice the empty intervals)

I have tried using `Buffer`, but sadly I need to partition by EventTime, not System.DateTime.Now. Even with boundaries, I'd need some kind of look-ahead since when I use Buffer(2,1) as boundary and compare [0] and [1], even though [1] succesfully breaks the buffer, it still gets inserted into the old one instead of the new one. I also tried `GroupBy`, but that yielded groups only after the input stream finished. Which should never happen. Then I tried some this thing:

```
var intervalStart = GetIntervalStartLocal(DateTime.Now) + intervalLength;
var intervals = Observable.Timer(intervalStart, intervalLength);
var eventsAsObservables = intervals.GroupJoin<long, Event, long, Event, (DateTime, IObservable<Event>)>(
        data,
        _ => Observable.Never<long>(),
        _ => Observable.Never<Event>(),
        (intervalNumber, events) => {
          var currentIntervalStart = intervalStart + intervalNumber*intervalLength;
          var eventsInInterval = events
            .SkipWhile(e => GetIntervalStartLocal(e.EventTime) < currentIntervalStart)
            .TakeWhile(e => GetIntervalStartLocal(e.EventTime) == currentIntervalStart);
          return (currentIntervalStart, eventsInInterval);
        });

      var eventsForIntervalsAsObservables = eventsAsObservables.SelectMany(g => {
        var lists = g.Item2.Aggregate(new List<Event>(), (es, e) => { es.Add(e); return es; });
        return lists.Select(l => (intervalStart: g.Item1, events: l));
      });

      var task = eventsForIntervalsAsObservables.ForEachAsync(es => System.Console.WriteLine(
        $"=[{es.intervalStart.TimeOfDay}]= " + string.Join("; ", es.events.Select(e => e.EventTime.TimeOfDay))));

await task;
```

I was thinking that I'd use GroupJoin which joins based on values. So first, I'll emit interval timestamps. Then, inside GroupJoins resultSelector, I'll compute a matching interval from each `Event`, using `GetIntervalStartLocal` function (truncates the date to an interval length). After that, I'll skip all the potential leftovers from a previous interval (SkipWhile expected interval is higher then actually computed from Event). Finally, I'll TakeWhile event computed interval matches expected.

However, there must be a problem before I even get to SkipWhile and TakeWhile, because resultSelector actually does not operate on all data from data, but ignores some, e.g. like this:

```
event.EventTime: 1s-----2s----3s----4s----5s----6s---
stream:          A---C--D-------------------F-----H--
```

and then constructs (from what it operates on, correctly):

```
1s-----2s----3s----4s----5s---6s---
[A-C]--[D]---[ ]---[ ]---[F]--[H]--
```

I think I must be doing something terribly wrong here, because it shouldn't be that hard to do partitioning on a stream based on a stream event value.

Comment: Why doesn't `.Window(...)` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you want. Given this:

```
time  : 1s-------2s----3s----4s----5s-----6s---
stream: A-B-C----D-----------------E-F----G-H-- (actual)
group : [A-B-C]--[D]---[ ]---[ ]---[E-F]--[G-H] (desired result)
```

It's not clear whether 'time' here is your event time-stamp, or actual time. If it's actual time, then that is of course impossible: You can't pass a list of ABC before C has arrived. If you're referring to your event time-stamp, then `Buffer` or perhaps `Window` will have to know when to stop, which isn't that easy to do.

`GroupBy` does work for me as follows:

```
var sampleSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))
    .Timestamp()
    .Select(t => new Event { EventTime = t.Timestamp.DateTime, Value = (int)t.Value });

sampleSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.EventTime.Ticks / 10000000) //10M ticks per second
    .Dump(); //LinqPad
```

The only problem with this is that each group doesn't have a close criteria, so it's a giant memory leak. So you can add a timer to close the groups:

```
sampleSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.EventTime.Ticks / 10000000) //10M ticks per second
    .Select(g => g.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))) //group closes 2 seconds after opening
    .Dump(); //LinqPad
```

This closing also allows us to return lists with `.ToList()`, rather than Observables:

```
sampleSource
    .GroupBy(e => e.EventTime.Ticks / 10000000) //10M ticks per second
    .SelectMany(g => g.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))).ToList())
    .Dump(); //LinqPad
```